# Movie about a man eventually being electromagnetically attached to a woman?

Tags: story-identification, movie

Peace and blessings. I have been looking for this film for years but I cannot exactly remember the plot (or name).  It was a movie that came out around the 80s or 90s where at the end of the film a man/teenager became magnetically attached to a woman/teenager (who as very dorky/geeky looking).  They are standing in a crowd and it is revealed to the man/teenager that he will be attached to this woman for the rest of his life.  He looks at her (in disbelief) while she was extremely happy.  As they begin to latch on to one another, the picture freezes (classic freeze-frame ending lol) and he is heard crying/moaning as the end credits begin to come on. Does anybody have an idea what film this could be?

Comment: I don't want to give misinformation (as I really cannot recall the title or plotline) but I think it was a part of one of those tales from the crip, horror movie type of films where it was a part of the story.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like an episode of Steven Spielberg's [Amazing Stories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazing_Stories_(1985_TV_series)), in particular Season 1 Episode 2 '[*The Main Attraction*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0511123/)'

From the Wikipedia synopsis

> A high school jock (Scott Clough) up for Prom King and feeling too cool for a girl (Lisa Jane Persky) develops a "magnetic" personality following a meteor shower.

[image]

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a link to the episode and a still